# Tailwind css "npm run watch" is not working

Tags: html, css, node.js, tailwind-css, magento2

I am working on Magento 2. We are using tailwind for design.
Here is my tailwind directory
`app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/web/tailwind/`

in here I have `package.json` it contains below code

```
{
  "name": "some them name",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "some theme desc",
  "main": "tailwind.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@some-themes/some-modules": "^1.0.4",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.10",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8.4.24"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npx tailwindcss --postcss -i tailwind-source.css -o ../css/styles.css --minify",
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development npx tailwindcss --postcss -i tailwind-source.css -o ../css/styles.css  --watch --verbose",
    "build-dev": "echo DEVELOPMENT builds are NOT SUPPORTED by tailwind v3, please use the 'watch' or 'build-prod' commands instead. && exit 1",
    "build-prod": "npm run build && npm run output-success",
    "browser-sync": "browser-sync start --config ./browser-sync.config.js",
    "output-success": "echo \"\\033[0;32mDone!\\033[0m\""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "author": "Some Themes BV",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "private": true
}
```

in the same directory I have `tailwind.config.js` which contains below code

```
const {
  spacing
} = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

const someModules = require('@some-themes/some-modules');

module.exports = somethemeModules.mergeTailwindConfig({
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'sm': '640px',
        // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }
        'md': '768px',
        // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
        'lg': '1024px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }
        'xl': '1280px',
        // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
        '2xl': '1536px' // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }

      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", "sans-serif"],
        'openSans':['Open Sans'],
        'squar':['Squartiqa4F'],
        'squarLight':['Squartiqa4FLight'],
      },
      colors: {
        primary: {
          lighter: colors.blue['300'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['800'],
          darker: colors.blue['900']
        },
        secondary: {
          lighter: colors.blue['100'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['200'],
          darker: colors.blue['300']
        },
        background: {
          lighter: colors.blue['100'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['200'],
          darker: colors.blue['300']
        },
        green: colors.emerald,
        yellow: colors.amber,
        purple: colors.violet
      },
      textColor: {
        orange: colors.orange,
        red: { ...colors.red,
          "DEFAULT": colors.red['500']
        },
        primary: {
          lighter: colors.gray['700'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.gray['800'],
          darker: colors.gray['900']
        },
        secondary: {
          lighter: colors.gray['400'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.gray['600'],
          darker: colors.gray['800']
        }
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        primary: {
          lighter: colors.blue['600'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['700'],
          darker: colors.blue['800']
        },
        secondary: {
          lighter: colors.blue['100'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['200'],
          darker: colors.blue['300']
        },
        container: {
          lighter: '#ffffff',
          "DEFAULT": '#fafafa',
          darker: '#f5f5f5'
        }
      },
      borderColor: {
        primary: {
          lighter: colors.blue['600'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['700'],
          darker: colors.blue['800']
        },
        secondary: {
          lighter: colors.blue['100'],
          "DEFAULT": colors.blue['200'],
          darker: colors.blue['300']
        },
        container: {
          lighter: '#f5f5f5',
          "DEFAULT": '#e7e7e7',
          darker: '#b6b6b6'
        }
      },
      minWidth: {
        8: spacing["8"],
        20: spacing["20"],
        40: spacing["40"],
        48: spacing["48"]
      },
      minHeight: {
        14: spacing["14"],
        'screen-25': '25vh',
        'screen-50': '50vh',
        'screen-75': '75vh'
      },
      maxHeight: {
        '0': '0',
        'screen-25': '25vh',
        'screen-50': '50vh',
        'screen-75': '75vh'
      },
      container: {
        center: true,
        padding: '1.5rem'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
  // Examples for excluding patterns from purge
  content: [
    '../../**/*.phtml',
    '../../*/layout/*.xml',
    '../../../../../../../app/code/**/*.phtml',
  ]
});
```

In the same directory I have `postcss.config.js` which containes below code

```
const { postcssImportSomethemeModules } = require("@some-themes/some-modules");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        postcssImportSomeModules,
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ]
}
```

In the same directory I have `tailwind-source.css` which contains

```
/* purgecss start ignore */
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import url(components/category-page.css);
@import url(components/product-prices.css);
@import url(components/cart.css);
@import url(components/customer.css);
@import url(components/forms.css);
@import url(components/messages.css);
@import url(components/product-list.css);
@import url(components/product-page.css);
@import url(components/wishlist.css);
@import url(components/modal.css);
@import url(components/slider.css);
@import url(components/structure.css);
@import url(components/swatches.css);
@import url(components/button.css);
@import url(components/theming.css);
@import url(components/transitions.css);
@import url(components/typography.css);
@import url(components/page-builder.css);
@import url(components/input.css);

/* purgecss end ignore */

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "theme.css";
```

In this directory `app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/web/css/`
I have my `styles.css`

Now in the terminal if go to `..app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/web/tailwind/`
and run `num run build-prod` it generates new css in `styles.css`

But when I run `npm run watch`
and if I change anything in my html,phtml files
It shows Rebulding has done but what it does is it only unminify my `css/styles.css`
It does not add new css as I change my html,phtml files

For example if I add in `footer.phtml`
`<h1 class="bg-pink-400">Test</h1>`
now `bg-pink-400` is a tailwind class but when I use `npm run watch`
It does not add css for that in my `css/styles.css`
But When I run `npm run build-prod` It does and changes shows up when I reload page

So basicaly command `npm run build-prod` works and `npm run watch` does not work.

`...app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/web/tailwind/` directory

[image: app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/web/tailwind/]

Let me know if you want to know code of any other files
Any help or guidance would be great.

**Update to my issue:**

if I make my `tailwind-source.css` file like this

```
/* purgecss start ignore */
/*@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";*/

/*@import url(components/category-page.css);
@import url(components/product-prices.css);
@import url(components/cart.css);
@import url(components/customer.css);
@import url(components/forms.css);
@import url(components/messages.css);
@import url(components/product-list.css);
@import url(components/product-page.css);
@import url(components/wishlist.css);
@import url(components/modal.css);
@import url(components/slider.css);
@import url(components/structure.css);
@import url(components/swatches.css);
@import url(components/button.css);
@import url(components/theming.css);
@import url(components/transitions.css);
@import url(components/typography.css);
@import url(components/page-builder.css);
@import url(components/input.css);*/

/* purgecss end ignore */

/*@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "theme.css";*/
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I have commented everything and kept below code

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Doing this my `npm run watch` command works and it generates css for classes as Add in any html,phtml files in `css/styles.css`

So maybe now if anyone can help why is that?

Comment: What are you using for the Dev server? I have had weird cacheing issues with some Dev setups

Comment: If you mean the website is in a local system or a live server, Then the answer is website is on a live server.

Comment: I have added an Update to my issue in question when `npm run watch` works if that can help to figure out what is the main issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution like this
app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themename/web/tailwind$
`cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
out put was - `29933`
we changed it to - `524288`

Now `npm run watch` command is working fine. It's adding css as I add class in any phtml files

Comment: how is that even a valid answer, this is dirty solution and user specific

Comment: @greendino do you even know what is `29933` and why we needed to change it to `524288` in answer.